# sending email invites to multiple users in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Basically i have an invite function, which takes the user written email addresses on a text box
and sends

```
public function invitePost(Request $request)
    {

        $validation = $request->validate([
            'to' => 'required'
            ]);

            $user = User::where('id', Auth::id())->first();
            $page = Page::where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();


             $format_branding = str_replace(
                array("##YOUR_NAME##","##COMPANY_NAME##", "##PHONE_NUMBER##", "##EMAIL_ADDRESS##"),
                array( $user->name, $user->company, $user->phone, $user->email),
                $request->message
                );

             $data = array(
              'format_branding' => $format_branding,
              'page_url' => $page->urlvanity,
              'name' => $user->name
             );


                Mail::to($request->to)->send(new InviteUsers($data));

                return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Invitation Sent');

    }
```

this is link which does the mail job

```
Mail::to($request->to)->send(new InviteUsers($data));
```

and $request->to is where user type one or more emails.
the problem is that it doesn't work with user types more than one emails.
for example example@hotmail.com, example2@hotmail.com, example3@hotmail.com

it won't work i even tried with implode and explode solution but failed..
i even made $request->to as array and foreach through email but its always failing with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.

Comment: Can you show `var_dump($request->to);`? When sending to multiple email addresses, it needs to be sent as an array (`['example@hotmail.com', 'example2@hotmail.com', 'example3@hotmail.com']`), not a string.

Comment: i cast it as array via explode but still got this error: Address in mailbox given [ example@gmail.com] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.

Comment: Then it doesn't like the email address you're passing in.  You can try trimming the addresses to remove any extra whitespace, and double-check that the email addresses are valid.

Comment: perfect, the whitespace was the problem. thanks for your help